# What happens in rugby game if the ball gets kicked into the posts at starting kick off?

Tags: rugby-union, rugby

I know that in the middle or the end of a rugby game, if the ball is kicked into the posts correctly, they earn 3 points. What if it happens at kickoff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Law 12 clarifies the result of any kick-off or restart kick.

Part 9 applies to this situation.

> 9. If the ball is kicked into the opponents' in-goal without touching any player and an opponent ground's the ball without delay or it goes dead through in-goal, the non-kicking team has the option of having the kick retaken or a scrum.

That is, unless the defending team keeps the ball in play and continues playing, they will choose either to make the kicking team kick again, or feed a scrum at the centre of the halfway line.